# I'm having problem running hugging face inferace API model

Tags: huggingface, inference

I'm trying to use huggingface inferance API,
but I am getting this error:

> {"error":"Model /Emoji-Suggester is currently loading","estimated_time":29.511520385742188}

How to fix this error?

I want to know how to use this inference API correctly

Comment: The model you're trying to use with the Hugging Face Inference API is still in the process of loading or initializing.